# Leveraged ETF for long term investment - quantitative analysis

Tags: united-states, investing

I know the question of why leveraged funds (eg. SPXL 3x) are bad for long term investments has been asked a lot. 
I have seen general answers saying that because of daily re-balancing and volatility decay one would expect to lose money in the long term.

To convince myself I have tired getting data from daily closings from the S&P500 and multiplying by daily returns by 3x (and subtracting ~1% annual fee).

Overall since 1960 I see a 12.1% CAGR for the 3X leveraged vs 7.0% for the S&P500. And over 20y periods it performed better than the S&P for 32 of the 39 intervals.

I am not suggesting putting a whole retirement fund there, as drawdowns can be very large (e.g. -84% in 2008, -61% in 2002), but those numbers seem to contradict the idea I had read that those leveraged funds are an intrinsically bad idea in the long term.

Am I missing something here in my analysis? Or are those funds really not bad in the long term?

Thanks.

The Excel spreadsheet I made is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1836cSCd3hghhnJwkZgOWjKq3nhXb-0h8/view?usp=sharing

P.S. I have also double checked that the SPXL does behave daily as 3x the SPX. When I compare the SPXL actual yearly performance vs the one I get from my estimate the actual SPXL performs consistently slightly better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some interesting information about leveraged ETFs (LETF) that I recently came across elsewhere.  I saved it because I'm always interested in  understanding market mechanics better to hopefully find an edge. I have not looked at historical data to verify the claim and  I apologize for failing to capture the author's name for sourcing.

> The more leveraged the ETF, the more sensitive it is to its index’s volatility. The mathematics confirms that when the index’s average daily volatility is at or below .756%, a 4X LETF outperforms the index the most, followed by the 3X and 2X.
>
> When average daily volatility is between .756% and 1.13%, a 3X LETF outperforms the the index the most, followed by the 2X, but the 4X no longer outperforms the index well enough to justify its risk.
>
> When average daily volatility is between 1.13% and 1.51%, only the 2X LETF outperforms the index well enough to justify its risk. When the bull market’s daily volatility exceeds 1.51%, you’re dealing with a high-volatility bull market. This requires a different approach.

Also, here's some recent [discussion](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/112686/do-the-rebalancing-costs-of-leveraged-etfs-really-outweigh-the-leverage/112689#112689) about this topic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the references. The reference you quoted seems consistent with my findings as over the full period the average daily volatility of the S&P was 0.67%. Also the other question you linked to gave similar performance to the one I had computed.